# Maximum value for different days

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I've got a datadrame with the following columns : Date / High price / Low price. About 300 trading days and the timeframe is hours. It's only for a single security.

I would like to find the code for the maximum high price for each different days.
Maximum high price for day 1, Maximum high price for day 2...

I can't manage to find the solution.

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC use [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) for indices by maximal `High price` per dates:

```
df1 = df.loc[df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.date)['High price'].idxmax()]
```

If need only dates with maximal prices:

```
df2 = df.groupby(df['Date'].dt.date)['High price'].max().reset_index()
```